# Push / Pull files in Calabash-Android tests

Tags: android, ruby, adb, calabash, calabash-android

I want to push files from active directory (windows) to emulated android phone.
My active directory is where my calabash tests are and I want to push the files to something like /data/data/appName/files/

I tried various ways of doing this, I tried to escape paths, also win and bash forms, and so on... Am I missing something?

```
#causes adb: error: cannot stat No such file or directory
pull("/data/data/cz.getone.jkr_mb2.phone/files/", "\%cd\%\\calabash-tests\\data\\someFolder\\")

#causes adb: error: cannot create file/directory No such file or directory
push("\%cd\%\\calabash-tests\\data\\someFolder\\", "/data/data/cz.getone.jkr_mb2.phone/files/")

system("#{default_device.adb_command} pull ./calabash-tests/data/sqlite/*.sqlite /data/data/cz.getone.jkr_mb2.phone/files")

system("#{default_device.adb_command} push ./calabash-tests/data/sqlite/*.sqlite /data/data/cz.getone.jkr_mb2.phone/files")
```

From the errors it looks like when I am calling push/pull inside calabash tests, the cwd is root of emulated phone (/)... How to access also cwd on windows? Isnt pull/push method supposed to figure out which path is inside phone and which is not?

This is how calabash pull method looks like inside... Idk how adb pull looks though

```
def pull(remote, local)
  cmd = "#{adb_command} pull #{remote} #{local}"
  raise "Could not pull #{remote} to #{local}" unless system(cmd)
end
```

Comment: Make sure your emulator is running `adbd` with `root` privileges - otherwise it won't be able to access the `/data/data/` folder.

Comment: I am using Genymotion emulator and it should be rooted by default, or am I wrong?

Comment: Also when I try manually push files to the emulated phone via cygwin by using adb push command, it works fine. But I need to do this inside the calabash test (some ruby file)

Comment: `pull` and `push` commands do have a fixed operand order - `push localpath remotepath` and `pull remotepath localpath`

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

**For Folder**

system('adb -s x push Folder/subFolder /sdcard/Downloads/Folder')

Where :

- Folder is inside the Current Active Directory where the command is launched
- x is the id of the device (use 'adb device' command),if there is one connected device then no need to specify it.

**For File**

system('adb push image.jpg /sdcard/Pictures')

For Pull command just follow the same pattern.